# Print in TableForm

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts, printing, table

Hi I have this code which runs fine, however it does not print things at the end in nice TableForm. I want it to print things nicely in the form of a table with some headings. However if I use TableForm it only print last iteration results not all. How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance

```
        xs = Array[x, 3];
        newF[list_List] := (#[[1]]^2 #[[2]] - 1) & /@ Partition[list, 2, 1, {1, 1}]
        newG[xs_List] := RotateLeft[1/Sqrt[xs]]
        newJac[xs : {Symbol__}] := D[#, {xs}] & /@ newG[xs];

        eps = 10^-16000;
        dim = 3;
        pre = 10000;
        max = 10;
        a = 1;
        b = Norm[newF[ts]];
        ts = SetAccuracy[ConstantArray[8/10, dim], pre];
        k = 0;
        While[k <= max && a + b > eps, 
          M = SetAccuracy[-newJac[xs] /. Thread[xs -> ts], pre];
          J = SetAccuracy[
            Inverse[IdentityMatrix[dim] - newJac[xs] /. Thread[xs -> ts]], 
            pre];
          hs = newG[newG[J . M . ts + J . newG[ts]]];
          a = SetAccuracy[Norm[(ts - hs)], pre];
          b = SetAccuracy[Norm[newF[hs]], pre];
          p[k] = hs;
          
          Print["k=", k, "  ", "a=", NumberForm[a, 20], "  ", "b=", NumberForm[b, 20], "  ", "hs=", NumberForm[hs, 20]];
          ts = hs;
          k = k + 1
          ];
        (*TableForm[Table[NumberForm[{n,a[n],b[n],t[n],a[n]+b[n],p[n]},10],{n,0,11}]]*)
        Print["The number of iterations is:" NumberForm[(k), 2]];
        Print["a+b=" NumberForm[a + b, 20]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eps = 10^-16000;
dim = 3;
pre = 10000;
max = 10;
a = 1;
b = Norm[newF[ts]];
ts = SetAccuracy[ConstantArray[8/10, dim], pre];

k = 0;
list = {};
```

To get a clearer display I reduced the `NumberForm` precision to `2`. You can of course change that back to any value you want.

```
While[k <= max && a + b > eps, 
  M = SetAccuracy[-newJac[xs] /. Thread[xs -> ts], pre];
  J = SetAccuracy[
    Inverse[IdentityMatrix[dim] - newJac[xs] /. Thread[xs -> ts]], 
    pre];
  hs = newG[newG[J . M . ts + J . newG[ts]]];
  a = SetAccuracy[Norm[(ts - hs)], pre];
  b = SetAccuracy[Norm[newF[hs]], pre];
  p[k] = hs;
  ts = hs;
  AppendTo[list, {k, NumberForm[a, 2], NumberForm[b, 2], NumberForm[hs, 2]}];
  k = k + 1];

list // TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {{}, {"k", "a", "b", "hs"}}] &
```

[image]

**Update**

For more styling options you should use `Grid`:

```
Grid[Prepend[{"k", "a", "b", "hs"}] @ list,
 Dividers -> {{2 -> Black}, {2 -> Black}}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Prepend[{"k", "a", "b", "hs"}] @ list,
 Background -> {{{None, None}}, {{GrayLevel[0.9], None}}},
 Dividers -> {{1 -> Black, 2 -> Black, -1 -> Black}, {1 -> Black, 2 -> Black, -1 -> Black}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

Comment: You're most welcome - and thanks for the accept :)

Comment: A quick question. How can I print the k left to the vertical and line and all other to the right?

Comment: See update. `Grid` has much more options.

Comment: Thanks once again

Comment: You could also look at `Dataset`